# displaying images and collecting rating score of each image

Tags: html, database

I have lots of images with filename as an identifiers. Each image has to be seen by users online and they can give a score/rating. How can I collect the data?

I have done it through Excel and collected the data manually. But now I am looking for an online based method as I know basic html and have access to a webserver. Please someone point me in the right direction or place for information.

Comment: I am looking for a plugin or web app as i have  to change images periodically and collect data. I know how to do if there are given set of images but images has to be updated periodically.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to run some backend script where you will pass the value of the image clicked and doing some database function you have to store it in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vast subject. For example you can store data in database (MySQL for ex.) and generate html pages using server-side language (Python, Ruby, PHP, ext.). And users interact with the server through the html pages. Your images information will be stored in database and change with script on server-side.

More details can be found here:
http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/client-server